# ¿Cómo puedo obtener un reporte generado por una consulta pivot con columnas dinámicas en Crystal Report para Visual Studio?

Tags: sql, stored-procedure

Tengo un **stored procedure** en SQL que genera una consulta usando **pivot** con **columnas dinámicas**. Es decir, ciertas consultas pueden traer 2, 3 o más columnas, todo dependiendo del valor de la variable. ¿Cómo podría plasmar esta consulta en un **reporte** en **Crystal Reports** para Visual Studio (C# o VB)?

Comment: Podrías indicar lo que has intentado para intentar acotar la respuesta? Por ejemplo, has intentado utilizar subreports para realizarlo?

Comment: Ya lo pude resolver. Estoy empezando con Crystal Reports, e investigando un poco, en la selección del asistente de Crystal Reports, seleccioné _Tabla de referencias cruzadas_. Inicialmente, mi consulta le aplicaba un pivot para tener unos registros de las filas como columnas. Con el asistente de _Tabla de referencias cruzadas_ ya no era necesario el pivot. Solamente vas seleccionando qué campos irán como columnas, y cuáles como filas, y qué resultado quieres en el cruce de esa fila y esa columna. Aún así, gracias por contestar, @MiquelColl

Comment: buena respuesta! Sería genial si pudieras auto-respodnerte para que así, en un futuro, cualquier persona con la misma pregunta peuda resolverlo. Gracias!

Comment: ¡Listo!. Gracias de todos modos, @MiquelColl

Answer (score 1):

Pude resolver este problema, y enseguida les pongo cómo pude resolverlo:

- Mi stored procedure hace una consulta pivot con columnas dinámicas. Tuve que **quitarle el pivot** a mi consulta, por lo que únicamente me muestra las mismas tres columnas de siempre con muchos registros.

El resultado(sin pivot) es algo así:

```
ClaveLMG Calificacion   Resultado
i7p-TP2 P1_1Excelente   100.0
i7p-TP2 P1_2Bueno       0.0
i7p-TP2 P1_3Regular     0.0
i7p-TP2 P1_4Malo        0.0
78-BD1  P1_1Excelente   100.0
78-BD1  P1_2Bueno       0.0
78-BD1  P1_3Regular     0.0
78-BD1  P1_4Malo        0.0
41-TP2  P1_1Excelente   100.0
41-TP2  P1_2Bueno       0.0
41-TP2  P1_3Regular     0.0
41-TP2  P1_4Malo        0.0
42-TC2  P1_1Excelente   100.0
42-TC2  P1_2Bueno       0.0
42-TC2  P1_3Regular     0.0
42-TC2  P1_4Malo        0.0
```

- Investigando un poco el cómo usar Crystal Reports, cuando tú creas un reporte en Crystal Reports, Tienes que seleccionar un asistente. Yo seleccioné **Tablas de referencias cruzadas**.
- Finalmente, después de seleccionar mi stored procedure (sin pivot), en el asistente de Tablas de referencias cruzadas, tienes que agregar *filas*, *columnas*, y *campos de resumen* desde los campos que genera el stored procedure.

Es algo así como si estuvieras haciendo una consulta con pivot. Seleccioné que quiero de *filas* mi columna **Calificacion**, de *columnas* mi columna **ClaveLMG**, y como *campos de resumen* mi columna **Resultado**.

`____________   i7p-TP2    78-BD1      41-TP2      42-TC2
     P1_1Excelente  100.000000  100.000000  100.000000  100.000000
     P1_2Bueno      0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
     P1_3Regular    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
     P1_4Malo       0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000`

El resultado es un hermoso reporte como si fuera un pivot.